# Join 2 different columns and then, search and match in mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

**"I have modified the question.." Sorry for misleading information.**

I have 2 tables, coin1 and coin2. They both have this column, "coin_code" in table, 'coin1' and "coin_code" in table. 'coin2'"

How can i join this two column from 2 different table into one column and then, i want to search and check if it is a match?

my sql query is:

> SELECT coin_code from coin1 UNION Select coin_code from
>   coins2 where coin_code="12345" ;

BUT

**The error i get is, that, i will get all the records of coin_code instead of just "12345".**

Comment: Does the column `coin_code` definately exist in the table `coins2`?

Comment: Oh erm, is it possible that i name two table as same name? Then i can do search and matching?

Comment: Instead of describing your table in words which are still unclear, can you be Explicit... `TABLE coins1(coin_code VARCHAR(10), other_field INT)`, etc...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT coin1.*, coin_code2.* FROM coin1,coin_code2 
WHERE coin_code="12345" AND coin_code=coin_code2;
```

You can use join also

```
SELECT c1.*, c2.* 
  FROM coin_code c1 LEFT JOIN coin_code2 c2 ON c1.coin_code=c2.coin_code2
  WHERE c1.coin_code="12345"
```

Comment: They're both joins - it's just that the first is in the (now deprecated) SQL-89 syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get data

```
select *,(select coin_code from coins2 where coin_code="12345") as result from coin1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your statement above is checking the table `coins2` for the column `coin_code`, but is it that the column is only in `coin1`?

```
SELECT coin_code
FROM coin1
WHERE coin_code="12345"
UNION
SELECT coin_code2
FROM coins2;
```

Comment: Oh erm, is it possible that i name two table as same name? Then i can do search and matching?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the two tables are indeed inconsistently named, `coin1` without the `s` and `coins2` with the `s`, and that you want to get the `coin_code2` data, you can use this select.

```
SELECT 
    coin_code2
FROM
    coin1 
        LEFT JOIN
    coins2 ON coin_code = coins2.coin_code
WHERE
    coin_code="12345";
```

The question isn't very clear on which table contains which columns, my assumption has been that both tables contain both columns.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also unclear but I think you want to filter *both* tables before the union. If so, try this...

```
SELECT coin_code
FROM   coin1
WHERE  coin_code="12345"

UNION

SELECT coin_code
FROM   coins2
WHERE  coin_code="12345"
```